# Custom domain for white label

Tags: dns, cloudflare, saas, cname

I have a CakePHP web app hosted on `app.mydomain.com`. The DNS of this is managed by cloudflare and I am using Cloudflares free SSL.

Now I want a client to use his domain as a white label.

> app.clientdomain.com        ------>     app.mydomain.com

This is not a domain redirection. I tried to find out and it seems something with custom CNAME pointing. Any help regarding this is really appreciated.

It is necessary for the app to have an SSL. The `app.mydomain.com` has an SSL, but the client might not. How do I cope with that?

I understand I can just tell the client to set A records to my server IP, but that is not what I want. I do not want to give away my IP and would like to use my cloudflare as DNS resolver.

I have tried searching everywhere for this and couldn't find much. If you could also tell me what this is called, I can hopefully search more about it.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

### Compare to similar applications

What is described in the question is a fairly standard thing. Compare with equivalent instructions from, for example, [google apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en):

> Follow the instructions that appear to add a CNAME record for each
> service address you're customizing. To add a CNAME record, sign in to
> your account at your domain host's website, not with Google.
>
> For example, to create the Gmail address mail.yourdomain.com, add a
> CNAME record that points mail to ghs.googlehosted.com. Your domain
> host records will look something like this:
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------------
> | Type | Name or Host | Value or Address     |
> ----------------------------------------------
> |CNAME | mail         | ghs.googlehosted.com |
> |CNAME | calendar     | ghs.googlehosted.com |
> ----------------------------------------------
> ```

### SSL

> It is necessary for the app to have an SSL.

You're likely to have problems with this. Because cloudflare isn't likely to even route requests that hit it for `app.clientdomain.com` unless that domain name exists on their servers. If you continue to use cloudflare's free plan, you or the client are going to have to add their domain *to* cloudflare so that it'll route requests - and if the client wants to use their own ssl certificate, that certificate needs uploading to cloudflare (which means: you or they need a business plan) as that's where requests for `app.clientdomain.com` are going to go.

All in all if this is your business plan it seems incompatible with using cloudflare - unless the idea is to force clients to use cloudflare too.